# Django inlinemodeladmin extra option not working

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm in the process of adding a user profile inline to the edit user page on django admin. So far the only problem is no matter what value I put in the "extra" option, the page always displays fields for 1 extra user profile record.
I don't actually want to display any extra records, but I can't get the extra one to go away. Hopefully someone can help, it has me stumped.

Here is the code:

```
#admin.py        
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = auth_user_profiles
    extra = 0
    raw_id_fields = ('organisation_id','advertiser_id','division_id','rtp_id','person_id','hp_organisation_id')
    exclude = ('specialist_id',)

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_superuser', 'last_login', 'date_joined')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active')
    search_fields = ('username','email','first_name','last_name')
    inlines = (UserProfileInline,)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

This is the relevant spot in the django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-options

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out now. Bit of a silly mistake really.

I upgraded my django version a while ago, but I forgot to update the django admin media files.

When I checked my apache log, I found a few js erorrs relating to inlines.js and a couple of other files.

Updating my admin js files with the ones from the django 1.3 package solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try setting `max_num` to 1 as well?

> If the value of max_num is greater
>   than the number of existing related
>   objects, up to extra additional blank
>   forms will be added to the formset, so
>   long as the total number of forms does
>   not exceed max_num

This from the [docs about model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#limiting-the-number-of-editable-objects), but it should work for the `InlineAdmin` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I wasn't aware of the max_num parameter. Unfortunately it didn't help, just like the extra parameter it doesn't make any difference. I must be doing something wrong here, still no idea what though...

Comment: Even if you set both values to 0? I just realised that `extra` is set to 0 in your example. `max_num` has to be smaller than `extra` (or equal) to prevent the display of further forms.

Comment: In this example only `max_num` is set to 1 while `extra` is not defined: http://blog.timc3.com/2010/02/18/extending-djangos-user-admin/ It's probably worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for your help arie, now that I have updated the admin js files, both extra and max_num are working as expected.