# How to implement admin meta fields in Django 1.3 User profile?

Tags: django

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MySiteProfile(models.Model):
    # This is the only required field
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

    # The rest is completely up to you...
    favorite_band = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    favorite_cheese = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    lucky_number = models.IntegerField()
```

The problem is that
`User._meta.admin` and `MySiteProfile._meta.admin` both return NoneType. I've dropped and recreated whole database, but no new fields appeared in admin panel; AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can make your MySiteProfile show up in the admin. One is to simply register your model with the admin, and it will show up under the app name it resides in.

Another is to unregister the contrib user from admin and instead load yours:

```
#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from my_app.models import MySiteProfile

class MySiteProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
  def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super(MySiteProfileAdmin).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    fields = list(UserAdmin.fieldsets[0][1]['fields'])
    fields.append('favorite_band')
    fields.append('favorite_cheese')
    fields.append('lucky_number')
    UserAdmin.fieldsets[0][1]['fields']=fields

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(MySiteProfile, MySiteProfileAdmin)
```

There are quite a few articles around on this topic, but hope that helps you out.

Comment: There was a ton of obstacles; I don't have to register own MySiteProfileAdmin, but rather re-register UserAdmin with InlineAdmin for MySiteProfile ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183132/django-inlinemodeladmin-extra-option-not-working -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400641/how-do-i-inline-edit-a-django-user-profile-in-the-admin-interface -> currently, it works ok..